# Co-Blogging on a Jekyll Generated Site

Tags: jekyll, blogs

I know Jekyll is officially supported in Mac and Linux. I am trying to develop a blog site based on Jekyll with another blogger and I will be the one maintaining the site. I know there are specify steps to running Jekyll on Windows (as shown [here](http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/)). We're both working on Windows environment. Can he upload posts without having to go through the Windows installation process?

I am new to Jekyll so please bear with me.

Comment: Upload posts to the site *how*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manage the blog in Git. Set up a shared git repo on your server and add a post-recieve hook. All your co-author needs to do is write Markdown files, commit to git and push.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Jekyll blog online with CloudCannon. CloudCannon can push your static site to any FTP account or to github. You can use their free plan. More info on [jekyllcodex.org](http://jekyllcodex.org).